# Can PiCloud hold FORTRAN code? (website hosted by GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, fortran77

I have a some old Fortran77 codes, which does some calculations. Now I build a website hosted by Google App Engine, and need to call those models' calculation results. Since I am new to both GAE and PiCloud, my basic questions are:

1. Should I first compile those Fortran77 code using a windows compiler?
2. Then, publish those models to PiCloud
3. Call from GAE?

Does my approach make sense? or Does PiCloud has Fortran77 environment, which can directly do the calculation without compiling first? If so, is there any example about this topic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picloud claim "install any library or binary written in any language", so it's safe to say you can run fortran programs on it. In fact, their homepage even says:

> You can deploy any software written in any programming language
>   including C, C++, Java, R, Fortran, Ruby, etc.

You shouldn't compile it with a windows compiler, because picloud runs linux - compile it using a linux compiler, such as GCC.

Regarding using it from App Engine, see [this page](http://blog.picloud.com/2011/09/14/introducing-function-publishing-via-rest/), where it says:

> [...] use PiCloud from Google AppEngine, since our cloud client library is not supported on GAE.

Comment: thank you! Also I got some feed back from PiCloud. They suggested me to create an environment, install fortran on PiCloud.